# How can I switch between std::map or std::unordered_map as a container in a class?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have this ifdef typedef in my class:

```
#ifdef HASHMAP
    typedef std::unordered_map<unsigned int, L1Entry> L1; //C++ 11 only
#else
    typedef std::map<unsigned int, L1Entry> L1;
#endif
```

I need to control what container is used when I create a new object of the class. What would be the best approach to do this?

Comment: So you want to do this at compile time or at runtime?

Comment: @szx I don't mind, would prefer runtime though.

Comment: if you want control at runtime: use the template solution as below and create 2 typedefs - MyClassHash and MyClassTree (or whatever you like) that alias the appropriate MyClass including template parameter (e.g. `typedef MyClass<std::unordered_map<unsigned int, L1Entry>> MyClassHash`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make the container a template parameter of the class:

```
template<typename MapType>
class MyClass
{
public:
    // ...

private:
    MapType myMap;
};
```

And you would instantiate like so:

```
MyClass< std::map<unsigned int, L1Entry> > obj;
MyClass< std::unordered_map<unsigned int, L1Entry> > obj2;
```

There's a container in the standard library that does exactly this, take a look at [std::queue](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue) by default it is implemented with an `std::deque` but you can specify another container, so long as this container provides certain operations.

Here's another version where you only have to specify `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`:

```
#include <map>
#include <unordered_map>

typedef size_t L1Entry;

template<template <typename...> class Container>
class MyClass
{
    typedef Container<int, L1Entry> MapType;
public:
    // ...

private:
    MapType myMap;
};

int main()
{
    MyClass<std::map> obj;
    MyClass<std::unordered_map> obj2;
}
```

OK! Here's a final version, to show you how you can split the code in .h/.cpp (everything goes in .h except for the section I marked):

```
#ifndef MYMAP_H
#define MYMAP_H

#include <map>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>

typedef size_t L1Entry;

template<template <typename...> class Container>
class MyClass
{
    typedef Container<int, L1Entry> MapType;
public:
    void printMap();

private:
    MapType myMap;
};

// START OF CPP CHUNK (replace with #include <whatever.h>)
template<template <typename...Args> class Container>
void MyClass< Container >::printMap()
{
    // ... do the actual printing
    std::cout << "You'd print stuff here." << std::endl;
}
// END OF CPP CHUNK

#endif // MYMAP_H
```

And this would be the main.cpp:

```
#include "mymap.h"

int main()
{
    MyClass<std::map> obj;
    MyClass<std::unordered_map> obj2;

    obj.printMap();
    obj2.printMap();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pedantic note: `queue`, `stack` and `priority_queue` are technically *container adaptors*, not containers.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid the part  std::map<unsigned int, L1Entry> and just have <std::map> (MyClass< std::map >)?

Comment: @Luis template template parameters, but it is messy.

Comment: Can anyone provide an example? I would prefer it that way because the types in the map are never going to change.

Comment: @Luis Updated answer with example

Comment: @Borgleader Can I implement it with the variadic template version having separated .h and .cpp files?

Comment: @Luis you cannot split templates in .h .cpp files. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: @Borgleader The class is big, so having everything in the header will be really messy...

Comment: @Borgleader Could I do it having this in the bottom of the .cpp: template class MyClass<std::map>; template class MyClass<std::unordered_map>; ?

Comment: @Luis What you can do, is split the declaration and implementation, but, include the .cpp at the bottom of the .h. As long as the compiler can see the declaration *and* implementation, it will compile. This is explained in the accepted answer of the question I linked earlier.

Comment: @Borgleader I ended up using the template with the separated implementation, I would love to edit your answer that is correct with the solution, so it is easier for other people to solve this problem.

Comment: @Luis I added the example with separate implementation.

Comment: @Borgleader I would suggest doing another example. The one you just posted is fine, but in my case would't work because the class is part of a dllexport and definition and implementation cannot be in the same files. The solution is using in the .cpp template class MyClass<std::map>; template class MyClass<std::unordered_map>; and not including anything in the .h. It is the last implementation option in your answer about templtes and .h/.cpp files.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this ?

```
  #ifdef __GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__ //Checks for C++11
      typedef std::unordered_map<unsigned int, L1Entry> L1; //C++ 11 only
  #else
      typedef std::map<unsigned int, L1Entry> L1;
  #endif
```

Comment: OP said "when I create a new object."

Comment: @Borgleader: The wording of the question is ambiguous.